# How to place cursor in NetBeans Java file templates?

Tags: java, netbeans, code-templates

I would like to have the cursor in the JavaDoc area when creating interfaces, classes, etc. in NetBeans. You can use `${cursor}` for non-file-based templates, but this doesn't work for file templates.

```
<#if package?? && package != "">
package ${package};

</#if>
/**
 * ${cursor}     <-- Inserts a message that "cursor" is an unknown variable. :(
 *
 * @author ${user}
 */
public class ${name}
{

}
```

Is there a similar mechanism for file templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason this feature hasn't been implemented (yet). See [this issue](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=211872) for details.