# Netbeans 8.1 code completion location of cursor

Tags: java, netbeans, code-templates

I have a single class like this

```
public class ReplaceIfRemove{
}
```

I have create a single code completion like this

```
public static void main(final String[] args){    
    final ${CLASS currClassName} clazz = new ${CLASS currClassName}();
    ${cursor}    
}
```

Everything works like a charm except that the cursor is not located in the next line.

According to the documentation states.

```
The final position of the cursor is determined by the ${cursor} parameter. This parameter is described in the section Reserved names.
```

But in my code templates shows like the class name is somehow selected works later when i press enter the cursor goes to the next *like the expected behaviour* see the next image for reference.

What i am getting.

[image]

What i want 
[image]

I now this topic is somehow simple but i could not find any solution on the web like this other topic [How to place cursor in NetBeans Java file templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10128996/how-to-place-cursor-in-netbeans-java-file-templates) and i want to dive more code templates in the future and i want to have some knowledge thanks a lot.

All i want is when i press tab the cursor goes to the next line not selection made is this possible?